# How can we create or set dynamic "Id" for button in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

Here is my code, it's not working.

```js
var that = this;
otable.bindItems("/", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
    cells: [new sap.m.Button({
        text: "Hello",
        id: "buttonid",
        press: [that.handleButtonPress, this]
    })]
}));
otable.setModel("data");

handleButtonPress: function () {
    var Button_ = this.getView().byId("buttonid");
}
```

How to set a dynamic id?

Answer (score 2):

To create a dynamic ID you will have to use a [factory function](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/284a036c8ff943238fb65bf5a2676fb7.html) on your aggregation binding:

```
oTable.bindItems("/", function(sId, oContext) {
  return new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
      cells: [
        new sap.m.Button("yourDynamicID", {
          text: "Hello",
          press: [that.handleButtonPress, this]
        })
      ]
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank You, also can I use  **id : this.createId("ButtonId");** in sap.m.Button to set dynamic id

Comment: You are right. this.createId will take into account the views id prefix. If the answer was correct or helpful you can accept it as correct or upvote.

Comment: Thank you.. @cschuff for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

`Id` is the first argument of [Button](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Button.html) constructor.

```js
var oButton = new sap.m.Button("id", {
    text: "myButton"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't supply an id to a `Control`s constructor an id will automatically generated. You can then access the pressed button using the event argument:

```js
var that = this;
otable.bindItems("/", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
    cells: [new sap.m.Button({
        text: "Hello",
        press: [that.handleButtonPress, this]
    })]
}));
otable.setModel("data");

handleButtonPress: function (oEvent) {
    var Button_ = oEvent.getSource();
}
```